# How to get second result of SELECT if first one is null in one query?

Tags: mysql

I have query :

```
 SELECT
        cl.id client_id,
        c.provider_id provider_id,
        c.mcc mcc,
        c.mnc mnc,
        c.cost cost,
        c.active active_cost
      FROM costs c
        INNER JOIN clients cl
      ON cl.pref_provider_id = c.provider_id
      WHERE c.mcc = 405 AND c.mnc = 11 AND c.active = 1 AND cl.id = 2
```

and if this record will not be found by appropriate condition, after i need to write second SELECT and try to get record by this condition (WHERE c.mcc = 405 AND c.mnc = 0 AND c.active = 1 AND cl.id = 2) in one query, of course

Could help me please? as less as possible query it's ideal :)

[http://sqlfiddle.com/](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57ea8/1)

Comment: Still struggling? If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Strawberry, thx, i tried to create up my bd http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57ea8/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NOT EXISTS() to check if exists a record with mnc = 11

```
 SELECT
         cl.id client_id,
         c.provider_id provider_id,
         c.mcc mcc,
         c.mnc mnc,
         c.cost cost,
         c.active active_cost
       FROM costs c
         INNER JOIN clients cl
       ON cl.pref_provider_id = c.provider_id
       WHERE c.mcc = 405 AND c.active = 1 AND cl.id = 2
        AND (c.mnc = 11 or
             c = 0 and NOT EXISTS(select 1 from costs cc
                                  where cc.mcc = 405 AND cc.active = 1 AND 
                                  and cc.mnc = 11 and cl.pref_provider_id = cc.provider_id ))
```

Comment: "Unknown column 'c' in 'where clause'"

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'and cc.mnc = 11 and cl.pref_provider_id = cc.provider_id

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
cl.id client_id,
c.provider_id provider_id,
c.mcc mcc,
c.mnc mnc,
c.cost cost,
c.active active_cost
FROM (select * from costs LIMIT 100 OFFSET 1) c
INNER JOIN clients cl
ON cl.pref_provider_id = c.provider_id
WHERE c.mcc = 405 AND c.mnc = 11 AND c.active = 1 AND cl.id = 2;
```